Autowiring how i can fix it
Can someone tell me how I can fix this error in my symfony application:

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error  Controller
"App\Controller\CompanyController::edit" requires the "$company"
argument that could not be re solved. Cannot autowire argument
$company of "App\Controller\CompanyController:edit0": it needs an
instance of "App\Entity\Company" but this type has been excluded in
"config/services.yaml.

Here's my controller function:
class CompanyController extends AbstractController
{
   // ....

#[Route('/company/edit/{slug}', name: 'company_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function edit(Company $company, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');

    // dd($company);
    $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $company);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // dd($company);
        foreach ($company->getCustomers() as $customer) {
            $customer->setIsActive(true);
        }
        $company->setIsActive(true);

        $em->persist($company->setUser($user));
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('info', 'Société modifié avec succès');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('company');
    }

    return $this->render('company/edit.html.twig', [
        'company' => $company,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}

    // ....
}

I've this error only in edit, show and status method.
It doesn't seem to me that there's an error in my entity or in security.yaml.

What's your symfony version ? Also look into https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html and https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-7-1-mapped-route-parameters

The error says there's something in your config/services.yaml file that's preventing it from loading the entity. Can you show the contents of that file?

Normally Symfony would take care of loading the company entity for the given slug you might have that functionality disabled or it might be the using slug instead of id requires a bit of extra config. The docs will have an example. The autowire message is not applicable in this case. Worse case is to just query the company yourself using the entity manager.

I follow the second link of @Dylan KAS, i just add in attribute slug:company
#[Route('/company/edit/{slug:company}', name: 'company_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function edit(Company $company, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

I try with MapEntity like MoWIz but no result.

Again what is your symfony version ? as Value Resolvers (old ParamConverter) changed a lot in the last few symfony versions

Symfony version 7.1

You can use the MapEntity attribute this way :
#[Route('/company/edit/{slug}', name: 'company_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function edit(#[MapEntity('slug'=> 'slug')] Company $company,Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');

    // dd($company);
    $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $company);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // dd($company);
        foreach ($company->getCustomers() as $customer) {
            $customer->setIsActive(true);
        }
        $company->setIsActive(true);

        $em->persist($company->setUser($user));
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('info', 'Société modifié avec succès');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('company');
    }

    return $this->render('company/edit.html.twig', [
        'company' => $company,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}

    // ....
}


Which will do what exactly?

The MapEntity attribute will "take" the slug you have in your route parameter and find the   company entity corresponding. The problem you have in the code you provided is that you are building the form without an Entity(because you cannot inject an Entity in your method). At some point "Symfony needs" to know which entity you want to edit... either by using the slug or another parameter
